# separate filenames string in windows explorer?

Tags: c#, .net, file, io

Note : I've edited tag to C# and .NET.

[image]

You can see in my above image I've .pdf files in my 2009 folder now my task is to get the string before `_` which is my id and the string which is file name and after `.` is the extension.

these all are the file names which are in my windows explorer under 2009 folder.

In sql I want to create table with three column which will contain like this for first filename.

```
1-AXJUHC_65927302.pdf
```

In sql I need

```
id             filename                   fileextension

1-AXJUHC       1-AXJUHC_65927302.pdf         pdf
```

such a way for all the file names.

If someone just suggest me how i can extract the above fields at windows level using bash or any other tools and then write this id, filname,fileextension to text file then
i can insert it into sql.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx

Comment: Bash or Batch? You write bash in the question but have tagged batch.

Comment: @Jodrell I didn't see `C#` tagged in the question?

Comment: @Jodrell BaliC I've changed my question to C#

Comment: @Bali C, you are correct. I guess, if using MSSQL you could use extended stored procedures.

Comment: @Jodrell Yeah I guess you could, the OP has changed to C# now :)

Comment: Would standard C# work for you?? Then I can think of a method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ( string filePath in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles ( pathOfDirectory ) )
{
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName ( filePath );
    string id = filename.Substring ( 0 , filename.IndexOf ( '_' ) );
    string extension = filename.Substring ( filename.LastIndexOf ( '.' ) + 1 );
}
```

You could use the FileInfo class as suggested by MrGTgo, but that reads a lot more data than you require.

Answer (score 2):

Use the FileInfo Class in C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx to get the full filename and extension.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"path");<br/>
string sFileName = file.Name;<br/>
string sExtension = file.Extension;
```

and to get the first part for your id use someting like

```
srting [] sFilename = sFileName.Split('_');
string sId = sFilename[0];
```

EDIT:

To get the all the files in directory:

```
Foreach(string path in Directory.GetFiles(@"Some_Path_Here"))<br/>
{`enter the code mentioned above here`}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

Get the `Path` of the file as you want [Let it be `filepath`] :

Then you could use :

```
using System.IO;

string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath); // returns "1-AXJUHC_65927302.pdf"
string id = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename.Replace(".", "~").Replace("_", ".")).Replace("~", "."); // for "1-AXJUHC_65927302.pdf", returns "1-AXJUHC"
string fileextension = Path.GetExtension(filename).Substring(1);// returns "pdf"
```